# Partition of graph by paths

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a non-null simple graph, and let $k$ be the maximum size of a set of pairwise non-adjacent vertices in $G$. Show that there exist paths $P_1,P_2,....,P_k$ in $G$ such that $(V(P_1),V(P_2),.....,V(P_k))$ is a partition of $V(G)$.

Comment: Do you have any ideas / anything that you've tried to prove this?

Comment: I am thinking that firstly prove that there exists a number n such that the collection of n paths could be a partition of V(G). And then, trying to prove that n=k. But I am having difficulty to construct the partition with n paths

Comment: Do you know Dilworth's theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585377/a-graph-theory-problem-about-covering/2585457#2585457

This should make an inductive proof work.

Comment: You've given an idea about approaching the problem in a Comment, but this should really be included in the body of your Question.  The interested Reader might welcome the opportunity to respond to your suggested approach either by critiquing, suggesting an improvement, or both.  It has been closed in its current form because no real context was provided, although context can be supplied in various ways.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove this inductively. We let $\alpha(G)$ be the maximum size of a set of pairwise non-adjacent vertices in $G$, and let $N[u]$ be the set containing the vertex $u$, and all of the vertices adjacent to $u$.

Here' a big hint:

> For any vertex $u$ of the graph, $\alpha(G-N[u]) < \alpha(G)$.

Another big hint:

> Consider a path $P$ of maximum length in your graph, and deduce that if $u$ is an end-vertex of $P$, then $N[u] \subseteq V(P)$.

Putting these hints together, you can remove paths from the graph one by one to get what you want.

Comment: But how can we ensure that we can remove k times? If we keep removing the longest path in the remaining graph and choose the vertex u randomly, is it possible we only get partition less than k?

Comment: If you end up with fewer than $k$ paths, you can just break some of the paths up to get up to $k$. The hard part of this problem is showing that you can find *at most* $k$ paths that do this.